# datetime picker with IOS(Chrome and safari) now allow save with asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem when I test the web application on IOS browser (Safari Or Chrome).

On Android and Windows everything fine but on IOS when click the save button the datetimepicker popup again and as user to select a date however it already is selected.

```
<form id="frmSave" class="form-horizontal" method="post">
@Html.HiddenFor(model => @Model.Id) @Html.HiddenFor(model => @Model.RepLocation)
<div class="form-body">
    @ViewBag.CanNotSaveLocation
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-3 control-label"> Date and time </label>
        <div class="col-md-4">

            @if (Model.status != null) {
            <div class="input-group ">

                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => @Model.Date, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Insert date ", @readonly = "readonly",
                disabled = "disabled" })
            </div>
            } else {
            <div class="input-group date form_datetime" data-date="">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => @Model.Date, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Insert date ", @readonly = "readonly",
                id = "date_act" })
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn default date-set" type="button">
                        <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                    </button>
                </span>

            </div>
            }


        </div>
    </div>


<div class="form-actions">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-9">
            <div id="y"></div>
            <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="btn blue" value="Save" />
            <button type="button" onclick="cancel()" class="btn default">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- END FORM-->
</form>
```

Comment: I have made some small edits to improve your post.

Comment: Your snippet does not say much, but my advise is to check the references and make sure that css is added before js